# 1D random-walker terminating position chance

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I understand that the title is a bit unclear, but here is my problem.

> Bob, a Random-Walker, is standing at position X. When he reaches position 0, he would be so happy that he would live there forever. (i.e. stop walking).
>
> But if he reaches position N, he would have a curse which makes him stay there forever.
>
> Every second, Bob has a chance, T, to walk left one unit. He also has a chance (1 - T) to walk right one unit.
>
> Determine the probability that he would find position 0 before he went into the curse (position N).
>
> Also, X, N are given as integers and T is given as p/q. I shall output the probability as a reduced fraction A/B with B>0.

Here is my question, but I have no clue how to tackle it. There are 3 subtasks:

> Default constraints: 0 < X < N ≤ 10 (so N ≥ 2 ), 0 ≤ p ≤ q ≤ 50 , q > 0 .
>   1.  N = 2 .
>
> > N = 2 is pretty trivial, just output the given p/q.
>
> 2. N <= 3 .
>
>    > N = 3 is already hard for me to get the logic.
>    >     Test Case 1: X = 1, N = 3, p = 1, q = 2 .
>    >     It turns out that there is 1/2 chance of getting it the first walk, 1/8 chance of getting it the third walk, ... (infinite geometric series)
>    >     so the answer should be 2/3
> 3. No additional constraints.  (No idea on how to solve)

Default constraints: 0 < X < N ≤ 10 (so N ≥ 2 ), 0 ≤ p ≤ q ≤ 50 , q > 0 .
General case... No idea.
Any idea or help would be great!

Test Case for reference:
X = 8, N = 9, p = 49, q = 50
Probability = 33232930569601 / 33925283289801

EDIT: I realise that markov-chains might be useful for this. Not sure how though...

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Okay, I would do the required edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discrete-time Markov chain with state space $I = \{0,\dots,N\}$.
$\require{extpfeil} \Newextarrow{\xlr}{5,10}{0x21CC}$
$$\Large 0 \underset{T}{\leftharpoondown} 1 \xlr[T]{1-T} 2 \xlr[T]{1-T} \cdots \xlr[T]{1-T} N-1 \overset{1-T}{\rightharpoonup} N $$
The absorbing states are $0$ and $N$.  The transition probabilities are
\begin{align}
p_{i,i+1} &= 1-T \quad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,N-1\} \\
p_{i,i-1} &= T \quad \forall i \in \{1,\dots,N-1\} \\
p_{00} &= p_{NN} = 1
\end{align}

The transition matrix is
$$ P= \left. \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0   & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
T & 0 & 1-T & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & T & 0 & 1-T & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & \cdots & T & 0 & 1 - T & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & \cdots & 0 & T & 0 & 1 - T \\
0 & 0 & 0   & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.}_{N \text{ columns}} \right \} N \text{ rows} $$

Let $h^0 = (h^0_i)_{i \in I}$ be the *hitting probability* of state $0$.  We have $h_0^0 = 1$ and $h_N^0 = 0$.  To find a relation between $h_i^0$'s, we condition on $X_1$.  For $i \in \{1, \dots, N-1\}$,

\begin{align}
h_i^0 &= P(\text{hit } 0 \mid X_0 = i) \\
&= P(\text{hit } 0 \mid X_1 = i-1) p_{i,i-1}
+ P(\text{hit } 0 \mid X_1 = i+1) p_{i,i+1} \\
&= p_{i,i-1} h_{i-1}^0 + p_{i,i+1} h_{i+1}^0 \\
&= T h_{i-1}^0 + (1-T) h_{i+1}^0
\end{align}

This gives the system $h^0 = P h^0$, but $\det P = \det(I - P) = 0$, so we *can't* take the inverse of $I-P$ to solve for $h^0$.  Usual techniques for recurrence sequences don't work here.

The trick is to take $u_i = h_{i-1}^0 - h_{i}^0$, so that for $i \in \{1, \dots, N-1\}$,
\begin{align}
(T + (1-T)) h_i^0 &= T h_{i-1}^0 + (1-T) h_{i+1}^0 \\
(1-T) u_{i+1} &= T u_i, \text{ so that} \\
u_{i+1} &= \frac{T}{1-T} u_i = \left( \frac{T}{1-T} \right)^i u_1. \\
h_0^0 - h_i^0 &= \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} \left( \frac{T}{1-T} \right)^k u_1 \quad \forall\, i \in \{1,\dots,N\} \\
&= \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^i}{1-\frac{T}{1-T}}\,u_1 & \text { if } T \ne \frac12 \\
i \,u_1 & \text { if } T = \frac12
\end{aligned}
\right. \\
h_i^0 &= \left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 - \frac{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^i}{1-\frac{T}{1-T}}\,u_1 & \text { if } T \ne \frac12 \\
1 - i \,u_1 & \text { if } T = \frac12
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
To compute $u_1$, choose $i = N$ so that
\begin{align}
0 &= \left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 - \frac{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^N}{1-\frac{T}{1-T}}\,u_1 & \text { if } T \ne \frac12 \\
1 - N \,u_1 & \text { if } T = \frac12.
\end{aligned}
\right. \\
u_1 &= \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1-\frac{T}{1-T}}{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^N} & \text { if } T \ne \frac12 \\
\frac1N & \text { if } T = \frac12
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
Conclusion
$$
h_i^0 = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 - \frac{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^i}{1-\left(\frac{T}{1-T}\right)^N} & \text { if } T \ne \frac12 \\
1 - \frac{i}{N} & \text { if } T = \frac12
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer from AoPS, and I would like to share it here.
Simply setup a system of equations:

Let P_X be the probability when starting at position X. and T be the probability to hop left and N be the cursed earth position.

`P_0 = 1`
`P_(n + 1) = T * P_n + (1 - T) * P_(n + 2)`
`P_N = 0`

From that, solve for P_X and that's your probability.

Elegant!

Comment: But to solve for $P_X$ is *not* trivial.

Comment: Ref: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-GRP.pdf